# How do I inject a DBContext into a service in Startup?

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I have a service that I want to use in a .Net core Blazor app.

The service uses a context that I want to pass to it.

```
public class MyService
{
    public AddDbContextContext { get; set; }

    public MyService(AddDbContext mycontext)
    {
        Context = mycontext;
    }
}
```

In Startup, I create the context that I want the service to use:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        //configure the context 
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HIDDEN"));

        //how do I pass the context?
        services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
}
```

How do I pass the context to service?

Comment: You don't pass the context to the service. The IoC container does that for you when it creates a `MyService`. Are you familiar with Dependency Injection? Also...you've got an AddDbContext and an ApplicationDbContext. Is that intentional that they're different?

Comment: Please, create an answer for your comment. Note that public AddDbContextContext { get; set; } should be public AddDbContext Context { get; set; } note also this: AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>

Comment: @enet I'll create an answer when I'm confident of the difference between AddDbContext  and ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: He meant public AddDbContext Context { get; set; } See also the constructor

Comment: @enet How do you know what was meant? Are you NetHawk?

Comment: No, I'm not a NetHawk, whatever that means. But this:  public AddDbContextContext { get; set; }

    public MyService(AddDbContext mycontext)
    {
        Context = mycontext;
    }                                                                                                                             leads the conclusion that AddDbContextContext should actually be AddDbContext Context

Comment: @enet No, it doesn't lead to that conclusion. I think it's far more likely that it's a copy/paste error in the question. But either way, we don't need you here making unnecessary comments. Please give NetHawk a chance to respond, rather than assuming you know their intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass the context to service?

You don't pass the context to the service. It is automatically done when the DI container creates your service.

Since your DBContext is named ApplicationDbContext, your service should look like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Note: You can only use DBContext in Blazor Server App

Note: I've only answered your question here. But it's very likely you'll have issues with the DBContext, depending on what you do in your service. You should consult the documents how to use the DBContext in Blazor, particularly, why and how you should use `AddDbContextFactory`